# Sort list of strings alphabetically in .net

Tags: c#, .net

How to sort list of words alphabetically in dot net without using any built in functions like Sort.

If I have a list of words : Hello,Awesome,Cool,Stuff
output: Awesome,Cool,Hello,Stuff

I don't want to use LINQ too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965337/sort-a-list-alphabetically

Comment: possible duplicate of [String "Sort Template" in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379234/string-sort-template-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Quicksort? http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/QuickSort_Recursive.html

Comment: @Sajeetharan OP didn't want to use any buit in functions

Comment: @YijieShen OP don't want to use any built in functions. It's strange, but I can't find any similar question on SO (sorting + C# + string + from scratch).

Answer (score 1):

You can use quicksort:

```
    static int partition(string[] arr, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = end;
        int i = start, j = end;
        string temp;
        while (i < j) {
            while (i < end && string.Compare(arr[i], arr[pivot]) < 0)
                i++;
            while (j > start && string.Compare(arr[j], arr[pivot]) > 0)
                j--;

            if (i < j) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        temp = arr[pivot];
        arr[pivot] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
        return j;
    }

    static void quicksort(string[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start < end) {
            int pivotIndex = partition(arr, start, end);
            quicksort(arr, start, pivotIndex - 1);
            quicksort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, end);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string[] arr = { "Hello", "Awesome", "Cool", "Stuff" };
        quicksort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
        foreach (string s in arr) {
            Console.Write(s + " ");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Source: http://www.bluesharktutorials.com/2013/08/quick-sort-algorithm-with-c-sharp-program-code.html. I've changed `int` to `string`.